# SSRS: How to improve the presentation of labels on a pie diagram?

Tags: reporting-services, report, rdlc

I have a circular diagram and I am using the keyword #PERCENT to present the percentages of the different categories. But sometimes the labels overlap.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F4gob.png)

I have tried different tag property settings but i can't fix it.
I have also tried to configure an expression, but it generates an error:

```
=IIf( Cint(#PERCENT) < 1 , "",  #PERCENT )
```

How can I improve the presentation?
Thank you! in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few things you can do.

1. To fix what you are already trying to do you need to change your expression to something like

   = IIF(
   SUM(Fields!Amount.Value) / SUM(Fields!Amount.Value, "DataSet1") <0.01,
   0, 
   "#PERCENT"
   )

The assumes the pie chart is based on a fields called `Amount` and your dataset is called `DataSet1` .

Then you need to set the `Format` property of the datalabel to something like

```
0.00;(0.00);' '
```

It's the part after he last colon that is important here `;' '` means, show zero's as a space.

2. You could set the label position to `Outside` so tey are not as close togther
3. You could "Explode" the small slices into another pie or move the these slices away from the main pie by setting the `CollectedStyle` in the `CustomAttributes` property group

in the example below this says "any slices that are <=20% or the chart" move them into their own mini chart.

[image]

4. Look at the `SmartLabels` property group in the Chaer Series properties.

[image]

Hopefully with this info you will have enough to improve your chart.

Comment: Hi Alan, Thanks for your answer, I solved it with the first tip of your answer, as follows: =IIf( Fields!total.Value/Sum(Fields!total.Value, "DataSet1") < 0.009, "", "#PERCENT"), the second tip (Explode) is very interesting, I didn't know, I will put it into practice

Comment: Glad you worked it out, SSRS can be very frustrating at times when you want to do simple things, and very simple when you want to do complex things !